# Parse xml and create java object

Tags: java, xml

I am new in Java and I have a task in my project where I need to get a java object from an xml. Which is the best library I can use? Thanks!

Comment: No "best" library. Google JAXB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the project doesn't already use any xml to java library then you should use jaxb which is contained in the jdk, thus you do not need to import another jar in your project.
here you have a nice tutorial about JAXB 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/

Comment: Thank you aurelianus I think that this is what I need

Answer (score 1):

I've used XStream a lot for exactly that. It's very simple to use, and seems to be pretty robust.

http://x-stream.github.io/

Comment: Thanks but standard jdk is better for me

Answer (score 1):

Hands down I recommend FasterXML. http://fasterxml.github.io/

The dev is very good about answering questions both here and on GitHub. It really is a library to be reckoned with.

Comment: Thank you but standard jdk is better for me